# Does the WordPress API have Modal Dialogs

Tags: plugins, api

Does the WordPress API have a Modal Dialog like BootStrap does?

In my WordPress Plugin admin page - the plugin settings page accessed through the Dashboard - I would like to have modal dialogs appear and allow the user to edit settings.

WordPress has the classes `button`, `wp-list-table`, `tablenav`, etc. I was thinking that there might also be a modal dialog class with some associated Javascript API functions to make it appear and disappear?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, WordPress has modal dialog and it is called as Thickbox, but I am not sure how flexible it is to implement what you want to. Here is the code -

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
     <p>
          This is my hidden content! It will appear in ThickBox when the link is clicked.
     </p>
</div>

<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=my-content-id" class="thickbox">View my inline content!</a>
```

Refer for more details - https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox